# Array of arrays from a dat file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dat file like this:

```
#  donnees t,x,y pour uid=12345
3.949218750000000000e+00 1.442828613651609082e+00 -8.307779446951960578e-01
1.125000000000000000e+00 1.005202962469742722e+00 5.323792795519278753e-01
3.281250000000000000e-01 1.133892308149918815e+00 1.321436062441114778e+00
5.449218750000000000e+00 -1.568679619747660459e+00 1.225514134192944526e+00
.....
.....
.....
```

And I would like to extract and read the data in a specific way. I have to define each column as T, X, and Y, in arrays, and then the function I use must return an array containing the 3 arrays when typing `return T,X,Y`

I've tried this for now:

```
def lecture(fichier):
    data = np.loadtxt('mon_fichier.dat', usecols=(0,1,2))
    print(data,data.shape)
    T = data[0]
    X = data[1]
    Y = data[2]
    return T,X,Y
```

But it returns me 3 arrays, not an array containing the 3 arrays.

Any idea about how to proceed?

EDIT: here is how I did it:

```
def lecture(fichier):
    with open(fichier, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        N = len(data)
        T = np.zeros(N-1)
        X = np.zeros(N-1)
        Y = np.zeros(N-1)
        for i in  range(1,N):
            line = data[i]
            d = line.split()
            T[i-1] = float(d[0])
            X[i-1] = float(d[1])
            Y[i-1] = float(d[2])
        print(T.shape)
    return T,X,Y
```

Comment: `return [T,X,Y]` instead

Comment: I tried but, I forgot to say, this function goes into a verification program and it returns me the error: ```operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (512,)```

Comment: Then just return the `data`. It contains 3 arrays. Also, you are extracting rows do you want rows or columns?

Comment: I want to excrate by column. And I know returning the ```data``` would perfectly work, unfortunately the verification program demands that it be T,X,Y that are returned

Comment: I have posted an answer based on my understanding. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
import numpy as np

def lecture():
    data = np.loadtxt('test.txt', usecols=(0,1,2))
    T = [[x] for x in data[0]]
    X = [[x] for x in data[1]]
    Y = [[x] for x in data[2]]
    return T,X,Y

data = lecture()
print(data)
print(data[0])
```

**Output**:

```
#complete data
([[3.94921875], [1.442828613651609], [-0.8307779446951961]], 
[[1.125], [1.0052029624697427], [0.5323792795519279]], 
[[0.328125], [1.1338923081499188], [1.3214360624411148]])

#data[0]
[[3.94921875], [1.442828613651609], [-0.8307779446951961]]
```

Comment: This is not exactly it. The issue is that I have the obligetion to return T,X,Y, not data or any other thing. So I have to say ```return T,X,Y``` and get the same output as ```return data```. Also, indeed I want to excrate by column, not row, that is to say T is the first column, X the 2nd etc ...

Comment: I would need something like this ```print(T,X,Y)``` gives, if i'm not wrong```[[3.949218750000000000e+00],[1.44282861],[-0.83077794]]``` You think this is not possible ?

Comment: Maybe. Let me give it a try based on your example.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let's see if works for you.

Comment: I finally succeded otherwise, I edited my question, you can check it up if you want to !